# change 3D line to 3D plane in WPF 3D

Tags: c#, wpf

I use C# in VS 2019 to develop WPF 3D project.
I have created two 3D lines in the viewpoint3D, which will move when moving the slider.
The customer want us me to change the 3D line to 3D plane, so the cross section of the 3D object could be show when moving the plane to cut the 3D object.

How could I draw a 3D plane vertical to X-Y plane and make cut the 3D opject to show the cross section of the raw 3D object?

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BylNu.png)

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="STIGenericReport.UserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:tool3d="clr-namespace:_3DTools;assembly=3DTools"
Height="407" Width="633" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Focusable="False">
<Grid Name="maingrid" Background="White" Height="405" Width="616" MinWidth="500">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="619*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height ="574*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="26" MinHeight="16" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds = "False"  
                IsHitTestVisible="false"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Margin="12,52,144,47">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <OrthographicCamera x:Name="camera" Width="2"
                FarPlaneDistance="10"
                NearPlaneDistance="1" 
                LookDirection="0,0,-1"
                UpDirection="0,1,0"
                Position="0,0,2" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light1">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light2">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light3">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,-1,-0.5" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D Points ="0,100,0,0,-100,0" Color="Black" Thickness="2">
                <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0" />
                </tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
            </tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D>
            <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D Points ="100,0,0,-100,0,0" Color="Black" Thickness="2">
                <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" OffsetZ="0" />
                </tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
            </tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
    </Viewport3D>

    <Canvas x:Name="canvasOn3D" Background="#00E6FFFF" 
            Margin="20,52,102,18"></Canvas>
    <Label Content="Trayinfo" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,0,0,0" Name="lblTrayinfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,257" Name="btn9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,232" Name="btn8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,149,0,207" Name="btn7" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,182" Name="btn6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,157" Name="btn5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,132" Name="btn4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,107" Name="btn3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,82" Name="btn2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,57" Name="btn1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,282" Name="btn10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,57" Name="lbl1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,82" Name="lbl2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,107" Name="lbl3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,132" Name="lbl4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,157" Name="lbl5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,182" Name="lbl6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,207" Name="lbl7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,232" Name="lbl8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,257" Name="lbl9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,282" Name="lbl10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Content="Pacakage info" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="32" Name="lblPkgname" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="204,378,286,-5" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,363,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="345" Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.434,0.409"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-115,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="338">
        <Slider.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Slider.RenderTransform>
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This can be done in pixel shader(fragment shader). If the world Z of the pixel is out of range, `clip()` the pixel.  And the plane can be generated from geomery shader. But I don't know how to access shaders in WPF 3D.

Comment: I do not know, either.......

Comment: Please elaborate with more details

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.material?view=netframework-4.6.1 There are only builtin shaders. Impossible I think. Try helix toolkit instead. It is open source and SharpDX based.